# How to create threads from the backing beans in JSF

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf-2

I know that this is discouraged b the specification but maybe there is safe way how to achieve this. I have a list of Runnables created in a backing bean, each of them setting some properties from the bean after the process ends.

In the prerender method all this tasks are started one after each other and in the gui, there is DataTable showing the status of them (there is a poll). After they all finish there is possibility to restart any of them.

The first run of all threads works and everything is set and correctly displayed. However if I restart a thread, it seems like nothings happens. Does anyone know about a correct way how to run threads from a jsf backing bean?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Within the EE container you should always have problems. When I need threading I make a call to a remote java SE program, running in it's own JVM, and this remote program handle the threads.

Comment: I've read about asynchronous, but how would I get the data from such a EJB method call to my backing bean? Will the backing bean method be blocking or not. And if not, do I have to ensure that the backing bean instance still exists? I've not found any suitable code example.

Comment: If you are using CDI  use **@Asynchronous** events for reference [CDI Events – Synchronous x Asynchronous](http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/05/asynchronous-cdi-events/)